# EFS File encrypted with "System"

Tags: encryption, ftp, windows-server-2012-r2, efs

We're trying to set up EFS to secure a file share so that only a service account can access the files in it. Everything works fine, until we try to have an FTP process send files to the folder.

- Folder 'test' is encrypted using account 'svc-test'.
- svc-test has full control over folder.
- Creating new files manually in that folder results in the files being encrypted using the svc-test certificate.
- Creating new files using an FTP process results in the files being encrypted and only able to be accessed using SYSTEM.

I'm not exactly familiar with the FTP process, so I cannot provide many more details there.

Comment: Ensure your FTP service on your server is running as this service account and not system or network service. If it's a service check to see what credential the service is running as from services.msc.